# Refresh ListView (or Hashmap?)

Tags: php, android, json, listview, refresh

I'm following a tutorial from androidhive (read and delete mysql entrys via php) and it works so far! Now I want to refresh the listview (if possible with "swipedown" - or if I open the ListView Activity). Because the entry is still there even if I have deleted it already!
Please help me!

```
public class AlleTischeActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://jvpoberstrahlbach.lima-city.de/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "tische";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "tischnummer";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray tische = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alle_tische);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        productsList.clear();
        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();


        // on selecting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            ...

            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AlleTischeActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Lade offene Tische. Bitte warten...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.clear();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    tische = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < tische.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = tische.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.clear();
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            TischActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /*** After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog ***/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /*** Updating parsed JSON data into ListView ***/
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AlleTischeActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.tischnummer, R.id.biernummer });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);

                }
            });

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: you can use a listener to an event and than refresh the view by reloading it

Comment: use SwipeRefreshLayout

Answer (score 0):

For this you should use the support library - `SwipeRefreshLayout`. See the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html

A good example of this can be seen here: http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/